# Getting extent of each individual feature in the vector source in OpenLayers?

Tags: features, extents, vector-layer, openlayers

i have a `vectorSource` that contains some features.i know how to get the `extent` of the `vectorSource`, but i do not know how to get the `extent` of each individual `feature` in that `vectorSource`.
i googled some posts and questions, and i tried to achieve that using the code posted below.

At run time, i receive the following error:

```
:179 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getGeometry')
```

as if the `vectorSource` does not contain any `features`.

please let me know how to get the extent of each indivisual feature in the 'vectorSource`
**code**:

```
const selectedFeatures = this.#vectorSource.getFeatures()
const extent = selectedFeatures[0].getGeometry().getExtent();
```

**update**:

for some reason, it did not work with `on('featuresloadend'`, and after checking the docs, i found the event to be fired should have been of type `vectorSourceEvent`, hence `addfeature` is used to listen to the fired event.

```
this.listenToMapFeaturesReadersInstance().value.getVectorSource().on('addfeature', () => {
    var features = this.listenToMapFeaturesReadersInstance().value.getVectorSource().getFeatures();
    features.forEach((feature) => {
        var extent = feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
        this.#msg = JSON.stringify({msg:verboseTag + 'evtListenerOnDrawEnd().', extent: extent});
        console.log(this.#msg);
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to get features from source before features are loaded. You have to wait for source `featuresloadend` event and then request features.

Sample code could then look something like this:

```
const style = new ol.style.Style({
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: '#eeeeee',
  }),
});

const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: 'https://openlayers.org/data/vector/ecoregions.json',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
});
vectorSource.on('featuresloadend', function() {
  var features = vectorSource.getFeatures();
  features.forEach(function(feature) {
    var extent = feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
    console.log(extent);
  });
});

const vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  background: 'white',
  style: function (feature) {
    const color = feature.get('COLOR') || '#eeeeee';
    style.getFill().setColor(color);
    return style;
  },
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
  }),
});
```

Here is working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/9qswahbf/

Comment: Thank you, tomorrow I will test it and then acknowledge. But would you please tell me how did you get this piece of information?I checked the official doc but could not attain it

Comment: Vector source events are described here: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html

Comment: would you please check the update section added above? can you please explain why `featuresloadend` did not get fired despite it is mentioned in the docs? and how to use it please. i know that ``addfeature` event works, but i would like to know how to get `featuresloadend` working

Comment: Your are obviously working in some framework. Since I'm not familiar with any of those, not event with node.js, I don't know why it doesn't work for you. See modified answer with complete plain JS code and working JSFiddle.

Comment: Would you please have a look at this question : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/478956/how-to-remove-a-layer-not-yet-added-to-the-vector-source